# how to overwrite local file and remove from server with int-ftp:outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

firstly thanks for attention
in my spring integration project i used `int-ftp:outbound-gateway` adapter to run command on ftp server, i want to retrieve file from server and replace with local file if exists else create new, and remove it from server, i wrote adapter code to perform operation,but not works correctly, my code is:

```
 <int:channel id="inbound1"/>

    <int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayGet"
                              session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                              request-channel="inbound1"
                              reply-channel="outbound"
                              reply-timeout="777"
                              mode="REPLACE"
                              auto-create-local-directory="true"
                              command="mget"
                              command-options="-R"
                              expression="payload"
                              filename-pattern="*"
                              local-directory-expression="'./backup/' +#remoteDirectory">
    </int-ftp:outbound-gateway>
    <int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayRM"
                              session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                              request-channel="outbound"
                              reply-channel="outboundRemoved"
                              reply-timeout="777"
                              command="rm"
                              expression="headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + '/' + headers['file_remoteFile']"
                              >
    </int-ftp:outbound-gateway>
    <int:channel id="outbound">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="outboundRemoved">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>
```

**in first step retrieve files successfully but does not overwrite files,create new,and in second when remove files from server, thrown the bellow exception:**

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to delete '//'. Server replied with: 550 File not found
```

Can i when receive message in check payload and if exists file send to remove channel ?